# Path to document. Adobe Brackets

Tags: path, applescript, adobe-brackets

Is there any way I can get the path of the front document in Brackets?

What I have tried:

With AppleScript this works well with most of the code editors but not with Brackets:

```
tell window 1 to set thePath to value of attribute "AXDocument"
```

On the other side, I have noticed that in the Brackets (menu bar) > Window menu there is something like:

```
/path/to/document.html (some-text) — Brackets
```

I would like to get only the path, without: (some-text) — Brackets

(Be aware that (some-text) I mean it is a text that is different in each computer. The common case is that is inside the ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    get has scripting terminology of application process "Brackets"
```

Returns:

```
false
```

So, scripting **Brackets** with **AppleScript** will be limited; however, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* worked for me to return the wanted portion of what shows for the *document name* on the **Window** menu in **Brackets**:

```
tell application "System Events" to set menuItemName to ¬
    (name of menu item 7 of menu 1 of menu bar item ¬
        "Window" of menu bar 1 of application process "Brackets")

set docPathName to do shell script ¬
    "grep -o '^.*\\.[[:alnum:]]*[^ ]'<<<" & ¬
    quoted form of menuItemName

return docPathName
```

<sub>Note that the `grep` *command*, if used in **Terminal**, the **regex** used for it would only have one *backslash* preceding the `.` to escape it to treat it as a literal `.`; however, when using the `do shell script` *command*, an additional *backslash* is necessary to escape it properly.</sub>

---

In **Brackets**, with a document opened and selected under **Working Files**, the **name** that shows on the **Window** menu for the selected document is always `menu item 7` and in the form of:

`/path/to/filename.ext (some text) — Brackets`

Using `grep -o` to return only the matched portion of the what's in the `docPathName` *variable* using the `^.*\.[[:alnum:]]*[^ ]` **regex**, it will return everything up to but not including `" (some text) — Brackets"`.

In other words, it only returns the `"/path/to/filename.ext"` portion.

**Understanding the `do shell script` *command*:**

- `grep` -  From its man page: file pattern searcher

  - `-o` - Prints only the matching part of the lines.
  - `^.*\.[[:alnum:]]*[^ ]` - See Understanding the RegEx: below.
- `<<<` - From the `bash` *man page*: Here Strings 
   A variant of here documents, the format is: <<<*word* 
   The *word* is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input.

**Understanding the RegEx:**

- `^.*\.[[:alnum:]]*[^ ]`

  - `^` - Asserts position at start of the string.
  - `.` - Matches any character (except for line terminators).
  - `*` - Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
  - `\.` - Matches the character `.` literally (case sensitive).
  - `[[:alnum:]]` - Match a single character present in the list, matches an alphanumeric character [a-zA-Z0-9].
  - `*` - Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
  - `[^ ]` - Match a single character not present in the list, matches the character  literally (case sensitive).

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>